# Returning owned pointers by reference

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose you are defining two classes, A and B, and B has a pointer to an instance of A, and is responsible for managing the lifetime of that instance. Like so:

```
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B(A *a);
    ~B() { delete m_a; }
private:
    A *m_a;
};
```

Would it be more appropriate for the method `B::get_a` to return a constant reference:

```
const A &get_a() const
{
    return *m_a;
}
```

or just return the pointer:

```
const A *get_a() const
{
    return m_a;
}
```

Comment: Makes very little difference as long as your class makes the ownership clear

Comment: No difference whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

> B has a pointer to an instance of A, and is responsible for managing the lifetime of that instance.

Is `B` an implementation of a unique pointer? There is an implementation of unique pointer provided by the standard: `std::unique_ptr`. I suggest using it instead of `B`.

> Would it be more appropriate for the method B::get_a to return a constant reference:

Depends on whether it `m_a == nullptr` is valid state for `B`. If it is, then you would need to throw in that case if you wanted to return a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, the difference between a pointer and a reference is that a pointer can be NULL. It basically comes down to whether the A* in your B class can ever be NULL. If yes, leave the code as is and return a pointer. If not, change the B ctor to take in the arguments for an A object, create the A object on the heap inside the B ctor and return a reference.